# Good "study" foods? Which foods imporve cognitive abilities, memory, concentration & overall mental performance?

Tags: nutrition, cognitive-science, memory, concentration, alertness-level

Just gearing up for a major academic exam -- was curious -- **what foods are recommended as "study" foods?** What foods should I eat while studying and for consuming on the day before/day-of the exam? By this, I mean, **which foods increase mental performance in cognitive abilities and boost concentration and activity and improve my memory while studying?**

Thanks.